# How is TinyVec the same size as Vec?

Tags: rust

[`TinyVec`](https://docs.rs/tinyvec/latest/src/tinyvec/tinyvec.rs.html#98-103) is defined as:

```rust
pub enum TinyVec<A: Array> {
  #[allow(missing_docs)]
  Inline(ArrayVec<A>),
  #[allow(missing_docs)]
  Heap(Vec<A::Item>),
}
```

However if you run this code you get interesting results ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bfc33a09499394fe818508bcdeeda3bf)):

```rust
use tinyvec::*;

fn main() {
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<Vec<u8>>());
    
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 13]>>());
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 14]>>());
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 15]>>());
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 16]>>());
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:4] std::mem::size_of::<Vec<u8>>() = 24
[src/main.rs:6] std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 13]>>() = 24
[src/main.rs:7] std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 14]>>() = 24
[src/main.rs:8] std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 15]>>() = 32
[src/main.rs:9] std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec<[u8; 16]>>() = 32
```

I know Rust can optimise enum sizes using "niches" - basically it puts the discriminant in some unused space, or even unused values of the variants. But I don't really understand how it is doing that for `Vec<>`.

There are definitely configurations of `Vec<>` that are invalid and thus could be used for the discriminant, e.g. size > capacity, null data pointer && size > 0, etc. But is Rust really smart enough to figure this out, or is it a hand-coded niche?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secret is that `ArrayVec<[u8; 14]>` is smaller than `Vec<u8>` and takes 16 bytes:

```
pub struct ArrayVec<A> {
  len: u16,
  pub(crate) data: A, // A = [u8; 14]
}
```

Compared to `Vec`'s 24 bytes, this leaves 8 bytes that `TinyVec<[u8; 14]>` is not using. These bytes being zero can represent the `Inline` variant, and them being non-zero can represent the `Heap` variant. In other words, the compiler is smart enough to use the data pointer part of `Vec`, which is `NonNull<T>`, as [the niche](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/glossary.html#niche).

Thus `TinyVec` is either:

```
struct TinyVec<A> {
    // ArrayVec (first 8 bytes are zero):
    this_is_null: *mut [u8; 14],
    len: u16,
    data: [u8; 14],
}
```

or:

```
struct TinyVec<A> {
    // Vec (first 8 bytes are non-zero and point to data):
    data: *mut [u8; 14],
    len: usize,
    capacity: usize,
}
```

Value of the first field serves as the discriminator between the two possibilities.

This can be observed with this unsafe code:

```
type TinyVec = tinyvec::TinyVec<[u8; 14]>;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<TinyVec>(), 24);
    let a: TinyVec = (0..10).collect();
    let b: TinyVec = (0..20).collect();
    unsafe {
        // XXX this makes assumptions about the layout of TinyVec and Vec
        // not guaranteed by rustc
        println!("{:?}", std::mem::transmute::<_, &(usize, u16, [u8; 14])>(&a));
        println!("{:?}", std::mem::transmute::<_, &(usize, usize, usize)>(&b));
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07baf05b4e8017d94bfb705eb7cf2259)

It prints something like:

```
(0, 10, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0])
(94630321433040, 20, 20)
```

The first line shows inline representation: null niche, length 10, and the array of values. The second line shows the heap representation: non-null niche (data pointer pointing to the heap) followed by length and capacity.

Comment: Ah the trick that I didn't realise is that `Vec`'s `data` pointer is `NonNull`. I assumed that it would use `0` for an empty array but it actually uses [`NonNull::dangling()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.dangling) (`1` in this case) and then it uses `capacity` to know if the pointer is valid.

Comment: @Timmmm I guess it could also test against `dangling()` without consulting `capacity`? (The end result would be the same, but it could be faster to compare to a constant.)

Comment: You can't - the docs say specifically not to do that because it could be a valid pointer.

Comment: Regarding your questions of whether this is a hand-coded niche -- not really, but it's also not fully automatic. The `NonNull` type is not a lang item, so the compiler needs to be explicitly told that it can't be 0 using `#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start(1)]`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think it's fully automatic from the vantage point of `tinyvec::TinyVec`, though.

Comment: Yes -- the niche optimisation only needs the flag, which is included in the source code of the standard library.